# Dropify text not centered

Tags: css, dropify

Have added Dropify to my site, but for some reason the default "Drag and drop a file here or click" text is not centered?

```
<div class="dropify-wrapper">
 <div class="dropify-message">
  <span class="file-icon"></span>
  <p>Drag and drop a file here or click</p>
  <p class="dropify-error">Ooops, something wrong appended.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropify-loader"></div>
  <div class="dropify-errors-container"><ul></ul></div><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fuImage" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fuImage" class="dropify" data-max-file-size="1M" data-allowed-file-extensions="jpg jpeg png" type="file"><button type="button" class="dropify-clear">Remove</button><div class="dropify-preview"><span class="dropify-render"></span>
 <div class="dropify-infos"><div class="dropify-infos-inner">
 <p class="dropify-filename"><span class="file-icon"></span> <span class="dropify-filename-inner"></span></p>
 <p class="dropify-infos-message">Drag and drop or click to replace</p></div></div></div></div>
```

Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

```
[class^="dropify-font-"]:before, [class*=" dropify-font-"]:before, .dropify-font:before, .dropify-wrapper .dropify-message span.file-icon:before {
  font-family: "dropify";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: .2em;
  margin-right: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em; }

.dropify-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #777;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s linear;
  transition: border-color 0.15s linear; }
```

Adding some text as more details since the damn script wont let me add the code if i dont. Adding some text as more details since the damn script wont let me add the code if i dont Adding some text as more details since the damn script wont let me add the code if i dont Adding some text as more details since the damn script wont let me add the code if i dont

Comment: As this is a CSS-related question, please include the relevant CSS!

Comment: Never mind, ill delete the question. Wasnt able to add the libraries to the append function.

Comment: We don't need the libraries, just the relevant CSS rules that apply to that element.

Comment: It wont let me add it. Says its too much code. Nevermind.

Comment: Then you are adding way too much code for what we need. There should only a be a few rules that apply to that element specifically.

Comment: Yes, those rules have about 30 lines of code in them total. And it wont let me add them. I cant strip code from it now can I?

Comment: 30 lines in total isn't too much. You are trying to edit your question to add them, and not put them in a comment, aren't you...? :)

Comment: Yup, trying to edit.

Comment: Then there's something else going wrong, 30 lines is perfectly fine. Sorry, I don't know whats going on in that case.

Comment: Added some stupid text in the end and it worked.

Comment: Bizarre :) Are there CSS rules specifically for `dropify-infos-message` and `dropify-message` (because that's the direct parent of `dropify-infos-message`)? `dropify-wrapper` has centered text, but that coud be overridden by CSS for either of those classes. But you could try adding `text-align: center` to `dropify-message` and/or `p.dropify-infos-message` (depending on what you want to centre) - it should work as long as there isn't a more targeted rule overriding it - if there is, change yours to have the same selector.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. In the JS file there are options that print CSS. For some reason, the text was within

and that caused it to be left aligned. Might be the underlying theme. I removed

and added 
:

```
message:         '<div class="dropify-message"><span class="file-icon" /><br /> {{ default }}</div>'
```

Now it is aligned.